# Filipino Green Card holders visit to the UK

Tags: standard-visitor-visas, filipino-citizens, us-permanent-residents

We are Filipino Green Card holders. Do we need a visa to enter the UK? We're planning to stay 7 days in the UK. We're going to meet my son's biological father. He lives in Belfast, Northern Ireland.

Comment: The UK government has a handy [online tool](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa) to determine if you need a visa.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you'll need visas.  The Philippines is on the [visa nationals list](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-visitor-visa-national-list), and there is no exception for US green card holders.